# Showing DIV after Form is Submit using JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, if-statement

I am learning javascript recently. Now am trying to show a div after the form is submitted along with the validation of the input field. Means if the input is blank the div will not show, and if the form is submitted along with the fields then the div will show. I have managed to show and hide div on the submit button, but the form is not checking the validation of input, it is submitting along with the empty div. Below is the code

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="#" id="form" class="form" >
                
                <div class="agent-details" id="agy">
                 <ul class="agent-information list-unstyled">
                  <li class="agent-link">
                   <a href="#">View Listings</a>
                 </li>
                </ul>
             </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                      <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="" type="text" placeholder="Name">
              </div><!-- form-group -->
                <button type="button" onclick="mySub();"> Send Message </button>
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
function mySub()
{

const user = document.getElementById('name').value;
const username = user.value;

if (username === "")
{
   document.getElementById('agy').style.display = 'none';
}
else 
{
    document.getElementById('agy').style.display = 'block';
}

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using document.getElementById("agy").visibility = "hidden"  ?

Comment: If you are submitting a form(without ajax) you are already going to load a new page. Are you sure JavaScript is what you should be using here?  This might be more appropriately done in whatever language you are using to produce the html.

Comment: There's actually a subtle difference, if you use <button type="button">Submit</button> then it won't load a new page, but <input type="submit" value="Submit"> Will do as you described.

Comment: @deadron the form is indeed using ajax and not redirecting to different URL. I want when someone submits the form the div should be visible. But when I try to click the submit button it doesn't verify and value field

Comment: Look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your problem is the way you access value from "name" input.

```
const user = document.getElementById('name').value;
const username = user.value;
```

The problem is in const username = user.value;

You already got username value in "user" variable, but somehow you did it twice here, with this statement: **user.value**, you don't need to do that. Because you tried to access 'value' property of the string you got **undefined** which is not what you want.

Just replace it with:

```
const username = document.getElementById('name').value;
```

and remove:

```
 const username = user.value;
```

Also I created the fiddle so you can try it: https://jsfiddle.net/yc14qto5/

Comment: this is hiding the div, but it is not verifying the input value, means it is hiding and showing the div even if the user field input value is blank. I am trying to avoid that and want to show the div only when a user fills the entire form and then submits it

Comment: No, it's not look at the fiddle I provided you, if you type something then it shows the div, if you don't provide anything in the input then it hides the div. Isn't it what you want? It is indeed validating the username field when you click the submit button.

Comment: thank you for the fiddle, I just added the CSS to the div and initially set it to display none and then it works like a charm. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad I could help :)